# Reloading data of tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my firstViewcontroller , I build a tableview.Its data are coming from a data base.In secondviewcontroller I insert data in the database,and I call function from firsviewcontroller to build the dictionnary data as I did in firstviewcontroller to extract data .All data are recovered from database but the tableview can't be reladed.I have no access to cellForRowAtIndexPath even numberofrowsinsection>0

This what I did :

```
Secondviewcontroller: 
//I insert data in database and I instanciate class where my tableview is and call refresh method

first = [[FirstviewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstviewController" bundle:nil];

[first refreshList];

//in Firstviewcontroller

-(void)refreshList{

   self.tableview= [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease];
    tableview.dataSource = self;
    tableview.delegate = self;

     NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//I recover my data from data base

    IPADAGRIONEActivityList *arrayActivities = [IPADAGRIONEActivity findAll];

    if ([arrayActivities length] > 0)
    {
        for (IPADAGRIONEActivity * oneRec in arrayActivities)
        {
            [array addObject:oneRec];


        }
    }
    //activities is NSMutablearray that contains all my data
    self.activities = array;
 //I build dictionnary 
    [self buildObjectsDictionnary:activities

    NSLog(@"self.act%@",self.tableview);
    [array release];
  [self.tableview reloadData];
}

//numberofrowsinSection: 
          NSLog(@"rows%d",[[objects objectForKey:[objectsIndex objectAtIndex:section]] count]);
            return   [[objects objectForKey:[objectsIndex objectAtIndex:section]] ;


//numberOfSection: 

NSLog(@"nbre of section%d",[objectsIndex count]);
                return [objectsIndex count];}


//CellforRowatInddexPath: It dosen't access to this method

if (cell== nil) {
                cell = [[MHCActivityListCell alloc]init];

            }
            IPADAGRIONEActivity *activite ;

                    cell.activityCategory.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [activite EMAIL]];
                }

            }
```

Comment: Should you be creating a new first controller or using an existing one?

Comment: in secondviewcontroller I try to insert data into data base then I call firstviewcontrolleer where my tableview exist to refresh it

Comment: No he should not be. It might be useful to post all of the code because you aren't exactly including all of the relevant parts. For example. `[self buildObjectsDictionary` is an opaque call, but probably the most important line here.

Comment: this method only build my dictionnary of data that I get from the database

Comment: But what does it do with the dictionary? does it set it to a property? does it return an NSDictionary? what is being done with the data?

Comment: This may not help but I have a method that grabs my data from json.  So I have a method called reloadTable and that calls my json function and then calls the tableview reloadData method.  May not help but hopefully does.

Comment: because my tableview contain sections and eact section has as title " dats" which is an attribute of the objects that I recovers from database.this dosen't cause the problem, because I use it in my viewdidload when I run the app to get all my data

Comment: My question is where do you set the new fetched data to your `objects` property? If you dont say `self.objects = newObjectsArray` somewhere, the tableview will be reloading the same data.

Comment: objects is an NSdiconnary.What I need is why I could not access to cellforrow or even viewforheader

Comment: Are you on the main thread when you call reloadData?

Comment: as you see , I call reload data just after I finish building dictionnary , numberofrows I get it correctly ,even number of sections , but It didn't access to cellforRow

Comment: `return   [[objects objectForKey:[objectsIndex objectAtIndex:section]]` doesnt have the call to `count` like you have in the nslog statement. Is this a typo for the question or your code?

Comment: I use the NSlog just to verify if it dosen't return 0

Comment: Yes but what you print with NSLog is not the same as what you return.

Comment: you are right it just mistak : this what I print and what I return :  [[objects objectForKey:[objectsIndex objectAtIndex:section]] count]

Comment: Are the nslogs called AFTER you call reloadData? This is just to check the the tableview is actually trying to update

Comment: What I know is while you call reloadData , numberofrows, numberofsection and cellforrowatindexpathare called automaticly..What could you suggest for me to reload data from onother class this is the problem , because I instanciate the class where tableview exists and call refresh method

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `self.tableView` is not actually visible. You re-initialize it in `refreshData` but you do not add it as a subview again with `[self.view addSubview:self.tableView]`.

As I said before, IT IS INCORRECT AND BAD USAGE to re-initialize the tableView, but it looks like thats the problem.

cellForRowAtIndexPath does not get called because the tableview is not visible so it doesn't try to display cells.

Comment: so I just need to add : [self.view addSubview:self.tableView] after initializing the tableview?

Comment: That should fix it, but it would be better to not re-initialize it in the first place.

Comment: this : self.tableview= [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease]; can't cause problem??

Comment: I have to delete this lines? : tableview.dataSource = self;
                               tableview.delegate = self;

Comment: The tableview property only needs to be initialized once. This should happen in `viewDidLoad`. After that, you only need to call `reloadData`

Comment: Move those 3 lines to viewdidload

Comment: And add it to your view

Comment: if I didn't use : self.tableview= [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease]; in refreshData self.tableview return null

Comment: the viewdidload is called when the view is loaded for the first time.But me , I am in the app, I insert data to database and I try to recover these data and refresh data table, so things that are in viewdidload are not visible .False??

Comment: Yes, it wont be visible in viewdidload. However, if you are calling refresh before the table view is even visble, that doesnt matter. As long as it is setting `objects` and `objectsIndex`, the data will be loaded when it becomes visible

Comment: if you are calling refresh before the table view is even visble : how to do that plz

Comment: You already are doing that. You initialize the view in your second view controller and then call refresh list presumably before it becomes visible

Comment: so what I need is only add : self.tableview= [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease]; and add it as subview in my viewdidload?

Comment: That should do the trick, you might have to adjust the frame in viewWillAppear, as in `viewDidLoad` the frame is typically `CGRectZero`

Comment: I added this but no result.